# ASP.Net 4.0 - Add Custom Task To Build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, asp.net-4.0

I'm using VS2010 and writing an ASP.Net 4.0 app.  I'm using DataServices and there's  an annoying bug where the compiler every once in a while can't compile successfully unless you make some sort of modification to the *.cs file that has the definition of the DataService class.

So, I want to add a step to the beginning of the ASP.Net build process that will modify the file with some arbitrary change before the compilation process starts.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the Solution Explorer, right click on the project file, select *Properties*, then go to the *Build Events* tab.

In the box for the prebuild command line you can do your prebuild task. You could do something as simple as a xcopy, or if you need to do some pre-processing of a file you can invoke a batch script or executable to do it. You also have a bunch of substitutable properties available to you if you click on the *Edit Pre-build* button and expand the *Macros* section.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is a web project in VS2010 and that's my challenge.  When I go to the project dialog there is no Build Events tab.

Answer (score 0):

arg.... just realized that I created this as a Web Site project rather than a Web Application.  Ooooops.  That's the source of the problem.